# Breaking children in to chunks and "react/no-array-index-key"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, key

I have a React component that needs to break down `this.props.children` in to chunks, and render each chunk in a wrapping element (i.e. a grid of child components).

I'm following airbnb's React linting, which includes a rule that [prevents me using the array index as a key](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md):

> react/no-array-index-key : Do not use Array index in keys

This rule specifies I need a unique key for each set of children that is not the array index - but I have no other identifier that I can use.

Is it ok to ignore this rule in such circumstances?

Comment: Here's an explanation that goes into more detail about when it is ok, and when not, to ignore this linting rule: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/12484

Answer (score 4):

Array indices make bad keys, since **indices do not uniquely identify a specific array element as such, but rather any element at a specific position in the array**. If this shifts, the identification breaks.

Do your items that make up each chunk have an id? Then you could generate a key e.g. by hashing a combination of the ids to uniquely identify each chunk.

---

If that is not an option, use the array index and ignore the message. You should try to avoid this however:

> When you don't have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the
>   item index as a key as a last resort:
>
> ```
> const todoItems = todos.map((todo, index) =>
>   // Only do this if items have no stable IDs
>   <li key={index}>
>     {todo.text}
>   </li>
> );
> ```
>
> We don't recommend using indexes for keys if the items can reorder, as
>   that would be slow.

[Source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: Could you point to a lightweight lib for creating unique identifiers for keys?

Comment: @RemEmber shortid